# How to use a button in an Alert in Javafx without using the .stopAndWait method?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to create a game in javafx where when you win an alert pops up saying you won and there is the option to play again or to close the program. 
The problem is to use a button in an alert window you have to use alert.stopAndWait() which doesn't work with timelines.

Is there another way to control a button without this method or would there be a better way to code this?

Thank you in advanced.

Edit:
Here's the code I have for my alert so far:

```
 public static void alert(Alert.AlertType alertType, Window owner, String title, String message) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(alertType);
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setContentText(message);
    alert.initOwner(owner);
    alert.show();
    ButtonType buttonPlayAgain = new ButtonType("Play again");
    alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonPlayAgain);
    alert.setOnHidden(evt -> Platform.exit());

    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == buttonPlayAgain){
        // ... user chose Play Again"
        System.out.println("play again");
    } else
        Platform.exit();
        // if user clicks exit
```

The problem is that you cannot use showAndWait with a timeline. I'm trying to find an alternitive to using showAndWait.

Comment: Why do you have to use `showAndWait()` to use a `Button`?

Comment: You could simply use `Platform.runLater` for this. `show` is available too, but you need to add some listener, if you want to get the result.

Comment: @Zephyr When using a alert in javafx, the only way ive seen to use a button use showAndWait as shown in the Alert class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html The most common way being  Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

Comment: Why you don't add an event to your button directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `show()` method, but you'll need to retrieve the result after the `Alert` is closed by setting an `onCloseRequest()` handler.

You can then determine which button was clicked with the `alert.getResult()` method.

Here's a simple program to demonstrate:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Button to show an alert
        Button btnShowAlert = new Button("Show Alert!");

        // Setup the button action
        btnShowAlert.setOnAction(event -> {

            // Create a simple Alert
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setTitle("Just a title");
            alert.setContentText("A fun message");
//            alert.initOwner(owner); // Remove for this sample

            ButtonType buttonPlayAgain = new ButtonType("Play again");
            alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonPlayAgain);
//            alert.setOnHidden(evt -> Platform.exit()); // Don't need this

            // Listen for the Alert to close and get the result
            alert.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
                // Get the result
                ButtonType result = alert.getResult();
                if (result != null && result == buttonPlayAgain) {
                    System.out.println("Play Again!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Quit!");
                }
            });

            alert.show();

        });

        root.getChildren().add(btnShowAlert);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using a button to show the alert. I'm using a button inside of the alert

Comment: That isn't the important button...that just shows the alert WITH buttons on it. I had to show the alert somehow in the example ...

Comment: Did you try running the example? ;)

Comment: The example you gave doesn't relate to what I'm trying to do. Look at my edit to the original post please.

Comment: An `Alert` is an `Alert`, no matter how you design it. The concept is the same.

Comment: You're using a button to show the alert while im trying to control the button that's inside of the alert.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to make it any clearer. Ignore the button that shows the alert. It doesn't matter HOW you show the alert. Look at how I'm HANDLING the alert and its result...

Comment: Specifically, when the alert is closed, you can do whatever you want with the result by calling `alert.getResult()`.

Comment: Also, the code you added to your question talks about the user clicking the "Exit" button, but there isn't an "Exit" button in your Alert.

Comment: I updated my example to use the same alert you use. Slightly modified the handling to allow using `alert.show()` instead of `showAndWait()`.

Comment: The user clicks exit was originally going to be another button but I changed it so that it's instead if the user clicks x on the window.

Comment: This helped some. I think it was confusing originally because I have my alert as a  method and I'm then calling it elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Well, essentially I'm doing the same thing. It's just that my method is embedded in the other button's `setOnAction()` method so it's only "called" when you click the main button :)

Comment: using part of this ended up fixing the problem :) Thank you!